# Memtest 86 for my laptop errors 'memtest86 unexpected interrupt halting

Tags: laptop, memory, memtest86+

I have a huge problem with my ICOM PrestogeBook laptop. Its parameters:

```
Mobo: Compal IFL90
CPU: Mobile DualCore Intel Core 2 Duo T9300, 2500 MHz
4 GB RAM, 2x2GB
Graphics: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series
HDD: SAMSUNG HM201JJ (200 GB)
```

I tried to run a Memtest to check if my RAM is ok, here are the results: (I tested one DIMM at a time). Results for the first DIMM: [image].

Then, tried to check another DIMM but then I could even see a BIOS scree, just whole black screen. And that's pretty all, since then cant turn my laptop on because I only see a black screen ... Whats might be the problem?

Comment: Sounds like you have a hardware failure.  If you tested each stick by itself, and every stick causes this error, then you have a CPU failure.

Comment: @Ramhound: thanks for the answer. I tested first DIMM and memtest gave me the error you can see on photo I posted. Then, removed it (there were no DIMMs in my laptop) and tried to check another DIMM. But then, my laptop didnt even start (there were even no BIOS screen). So I tred to switch to the first DIMM (that one that caused errors) and even with it, it didnt start

Comment: As Ramhound said, it's a hardware failure, and the RAM probably isn't at fault.  Look like motherboard failure to me, but could be lots of things.

Comment: @yak - While your CPU being the cause is very likely based on the behavior you described before, your system also, very likely requires all the slots to be populated.  The failure describe with memtestx86 isn't a memory failure at least not directly.

Comment: @techie007: is it possible? Before I tested and took out DIMMs from slots, laptop worked ...

Comment: @Ramhound: what else should I (and how) check to be 100% sure what caused the problem?

Comment: @yak - You can't be 100% sure of anything.  If your laptop cannot even turn you can't troubleshoot any further.